# How to add a JNDI to a Crystal report bean?

Tags: java, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

All.

I found an example for a "**Crystal Report PDF converter**" on SAP's page. It works fine on "simple" reports, but when a report contains database connection it fails. Here's what I've got:

```
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.*;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.exportoptions.*;

//Java imports.
import java.io.*;

public class Reader {

//  static final String REPORT_NAME = "C:\\works_fine.rpt";
    static final String REPORT_NAME = "C:\\problematic.rpt";
    static final String EXPORT_FILE = "C:\\myExportedReport.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            // Open report.
            ReportClientDocument reportClientDoc = new ReportClientDocument();
            reportClientDoc.open(REPORT_NAME, 0);

            // NOTE: If parameters or database login credentials are required,
            // they need to be set before.
            // calling the export() method of the PrintOutputController.

            // Export report and obtain an input stream that can be written to
            // disk.
            // See the Java Reporting Component Developer's Guide for more
            // information on the supported export format enumerations
            // possible with the JRC.
            ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = (ByteArrayInputStream) reportClientDoc
                    .getPrintOutputController().export(ReportExportFormat.PDF);

            // Release report.
            reportClientDoc.close();

            // Use the Java I/O libraries to write the exported content to the
            // file system.
            byte byteArray[] = new byte[byteArrayInputStream.available()];

            // Create a new file that will contain the exported result.
            File file = new File(EXPORT_FILE);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
                    byteArrayInputStream.available());
            int x = byteArrayInputStream.read(byteArray, 0,
                    byteArrayInputStream.available());

            byteArrayOutputStream.write(byteArray, 0, x);
            byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(fileOutputStream);

            // Close streams.
            byteArrayInputStream.close();
            byteArrayOutputStream.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();

            System.out
                    .println("Successfully exported report to " + EXPORT_FILE);

        } catch (ReportSDKException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

I even added the following before the export call, but it still failed:

```
   oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource ds 
        = new oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource();
      ds.setDriverType("thin");
      ds.setServerName("server");
      ds.setPortNumber(123);
      ds.setDatabaseName("database");
      ds.setPassword("password");
      ds.setUser("user");
```

As a mentioned before, when I use the "works_fine" report, It works like a champ, but once I use the "problematic" report, this happens:

```
com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKException: Error finding JNDI name (THENAME)---- Error code:-2147467259 Error code name:failed
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.if(SourceFile:237)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.export(SourceFile:147)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.export(SourceFile:128)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.export(SourceFile:111)
    at gac.read.Reader.main(Reader.java:49)
Caused by: com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.JndiNotFoundException: Error finding JNDI name (THENAME)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.queryengine.Connection.a(SourceFile:1871)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.queryengine.Connection.br(SourceFile:1815)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.queryengine.Connection.bs(SourceFile:505)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.queryengine.Connection.t4(SourceFile:3020)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.dfadapter.DFAdapter.a(SourceFile:697)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.dfadapter.DFAdapter.for(SourceFile:707)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.reportdefinition.ReportHelper.a(SourceFile:198)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.requesthandler.ReportViewingRequestHandler.long(SourceFile:958)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.requesthandler.ReportViewingRequestHandler.a(SourceFile:636)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.requesthandler.ReportViewingRequestHandler.int(SourceFile:673)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.do(SourceFile:1943)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.if(SourceFile:660)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.a(SourceFile:166)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter$2.a(SourceFile:528)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter$2.call(SourceFile:526)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.ThreadGuard.syncExecute(SourceFile:102)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.for(SourceFile:524)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.int(SourceFile:423)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.request(SourceFile:351)
    at com.businessobjects.sdk.erom.jrc.a.a(SourceFile:54)
    at com.businessobjects.sdk.erom.jrc.a.execute(SourceFile:67)
    at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.RemoteAgent$a.execute(SourceFile:716)
    at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.CommunicationChannel.a(SourceFile:125)
    at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.RemoteAgent.a(SourceFile:537)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ds.a(SourceFile:186)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportSource.a(SourceFile:1558)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportSource.a(SourceFile:337)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.if(SourceFile:223)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.businessobjects.reports.jdbinterface.common.DBException: Error finding JNDI name (THENAME)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.queryengine.driverImpl.jdbc.JDBCConnection.Open(Unknown Source)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.queryengine.JDBConnectionWrapper.Open(SourceFile:123)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.queryengine.Connection.br(SourceFile:1786)
    ... 30 more
```

It is worth mentioning that I'm new to Crystal Reports and creating JNDI names.

Any kind of help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by overwriting the connection properties:

```
package com.org;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.data.ConnectionInfoKind;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.data.IConnectionInfo;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.data.ITable;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.exportoptions.ReportExportFormat;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.PropertyBag;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKException;

public class YetAnotherReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //Overwrite any existing properties with updated values.
            //information Oracle database
            String DBUSERNAME = "user";
            String DBPASSWORD = "password";
            String SERVERNAME = "server";
            String PORT = "1521";
            String DATABASE_NAME = "databaseName"; // SID or Instance
            String URI = "!oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver!jdbc:oracle:thin:{userid}/{password}@" + SERVERNAME + ":" + PORT + "/" + DATABASE_NAME;  //1521/ or :1521
            String DATABASE_DLL = "crdb_jdbc.dll";
            //end
            
            String report_name = "C:\\myReport.rpt";
            String exportFileName = "C:\\fileName.pdf";
            ReportClientDocument clientDoc = new ReportClientDocument();
            clientDoc.open(report_name, ReportExportFormat._PDF);
     
            // Obtain collection of tables from this database controller.
            ITable table = clientDoc.getDatabaseController().getDatabase().getTables().getTable(0);
     
            IConnectionInfo connectionInfo = table.getConnectionInfo();
            PropertyBag propertyBag = connectionInfo.getAttributes();
            propertyBag.clear();
     
            //Overwrite any existing properties with updated values.
            propertyBag.put("Trusted_Connection", "false");
            propertyBag.put("Server Name", SERVERNAME); //Optional property.
            propertyBag.put("Database Name", DATABASE_NAME);
            propertyBag.put("Server Type", "JDBC (JNDI)");
            propertyBag.put("URI", URI);
            propertyBag.put("Use JDBC", "true");
            propertyBag.put("Database DLL", DATABASE_DLL);
            connectionInfo.setAttributes(propertyBag);
     
            //Set database username and password.
            //NOTE: Even if these the username and password properties don't change when switching databases, the 
            //database password is *not* saved in the report and must be set at runtime if the database is secured.  
            connectionInfo.setUserName(DBUSERNAME);
            connectionInfo.setPassword(DBPASSWORD);
            connectionInfo.setKind(ConnectionInfoKind.SQL);
     
            table.setConnectionInfo(connectionInfo);
            //Update old table in the report with the new table.
            clientDoc.getDatabaseController().setTableLocation(table, table);
     
            clientDoc.getDataDefController().getParameterFieldController().setCurrentValue("", "pk_id", 14);
            //Writing into PDF file
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = (ByteArrayInputStream) clientDoc.getPrintOutputController().export(ReportExportFormat.PDF);
            int size = bais.available();
            byte[] barray = new byte[size];
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(exportFileName));
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(size);
            int bytes = bais.read(barray, 0, size);
            baos.write(barray, 0, bytes);
            baos.writeTo(fos);
            clientDoc.close();
            bais.close();
            baos.close();
            fos.close();
            //dbConn.close();
     
        } catch (ReportSDKException ex) {
            System.out.println("ReportSDKException" + ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception" + ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Also, please notice the use of a primary key on (You might want to change that, too):

```
clientDoc.getDataDefController().getParameterFieldController().setCurrentValue("", "pk_id", 14);
```

"pk_id" is a parameter used on the report. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM myTableOrView WHERE id < {?pk_id}
```

Source: [Here](http://lvtutorial.com/core-java/export-crystal-report-to-pdf-in-java.html)

Edit: Are you getting the following error? `com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKException: Unexpected ValueType: ValueType=[255]`

Check Marco Tizzano's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76854407/how-to-open-cr-report-based-on-hana-db-with-java)

Comment: Take note, If you are failing on the opening of the report. you might want to add the following line to above the open report. `System.setProperty("java.version", "1.8.0_254");`

Comment: Also just so you know your link is broken where it says source on the bottom. Please repost your source as it would be helpful.

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch I believe the server is down ):

Comment: No problem. This has been a tough problem for me. If you have any other resources on how you did this please share. It was pretty fricken difficult to get this working.

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch Unfortunately, the company I worked for cancelled this project. Also, it seems like every helpful post/source is now down. I do apologize for the inconveniences.

Comment: Hi @Cempoalxóchitl. I've been trying to use your code as basis for my own implementation. Unfortunately, I can't manage to get it worked, because when invoking `clientDoc.getDatabaseController().setTableLocation(...)` method, it throws an exception like this:

`com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKException: Unexpected ValueType: ValueType=[255]`

I have submitted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76854407/how-to-open-cr-report-with-java-11-based-on-hana-db

As you faced similar issues, your feedback on the topic would be highly appreciated. Thank you.